# How to make a bean as a custom type?

Tags: java, spring

```
class Proxy{
  private Class<?> customType;
  ..
}
interface Foo{
  public String foo();
  ..
}
<bean id="foo" class="com.test.Proxy">
  <property name="customType" value="com.test.Foo"/>
</bean>
```

**Except**

Bean foo is the instances of `com.test.Foo`,not `com.test.Proxy`

**Question**

How should I do in the Proxy class,it's seems spring provide a interface to do with this, but i really don't know how to achieve this?

I also search by google,but don't find it,maybe the keyword I used was wrong,can anyone help or give a guide link to me, thanks very much.

**Result**

```
class Proxy<T> implements FactoryBean<T>{
  private Class<?> customType;
  public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return customType;
  }
  public T getObject() throws Exception {
        return (T)customObj;
  }
  ..
}
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at Java's java.lang.reflect.Proxy and the InvocationHandler mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide an implementation of Foo, as you must instantiate the implementation and not the interface:

```
class Proxy{
  private Foo customType;
  ..
}

interface Foo{
  public String foo();
  ..
}

class FooImpl implements Foo{
  public String foo();
  ...
}
```

Then in the xml, set it like this:

```
<bean id="foo" class="com.test.Proxy">
  <property name="customType">
     <bean class="com.test.FooImpl" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks, i know how to do it now, just implement `FactoryBean`'s  `getObjectType` and `getObject`